# Why cannot I close the world of my ontology

Tags: python, owl, ontology, owlready

I defined some classes under my ontology. But I faced with a problem,
I cannot close the world of my ontology lib. To my surprise, if I rewrite `Teacher class` as

```
class Teacher(Employee):
            equivalent_to = [Person & empolied.min(1, University)]
```

or

```
class Teacher(Employee):
            equivalent_to = [Person & empolied.min(1, College)]
```

even

```
class Teacher(Employee):
            equivalent_to = [Person]
```

it will be closed successfully. It seams that the problem is raised from the expression `University | College`.

Moreover, I can close any class in the ontology including `Thing`.

What is the reason?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from owlready2 import *
import datetime
society = get_ontology("http://test.org/society.owl")

with society:
    class Person(Thing):
        def __ini__(self, wholename='', birthday=None, gender='male', *args, **kwargs):
            super(Person, self).__ini__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.wholename = wholename
            self.birthday = birthday
            self.gender = gender
            self.info = ''

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s (%s, %s)'%(self.wholename, self.birthday, self.gender)


    class Orgonization(Thing):
        def __ini__(self, wholename='', birthday=0, members=[], taxno='', *args, **kwargs):
            super(Person, self).__ini__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.wholename = wholename
            self.birthday = birthday
            self.members = members
            self.taxno = taxno
            self.info = ''


    class Institution(Orgonization):
        pass

    class University(Institution):
        pass

    class College(Institution):
        pass

    class Employee(Person):
        def __ini__(self, no=0, level=0, salary=0, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Person, self).__ini__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.no = no
            self.level = level
            self.salary = salary

        def show_info(self):
            print(self)
            print('no: %s\nlevel: %d\nsalary: %.2f'%(self.no, self.level, self.salary))

    class empolied(Employee >> Orgonization):
        pass

    class empoly(Orgonization >> Employee):
        inverse_property = empolied

    class friend(Person >> Person, SymmetricProperty):
        pass


    class Teacher(Employee):
        equivalent_to = [Person & empolied.min(1, University | College)]


zjc = College('zjc', wholename='***', taxno='***')

song = Teacher('songcw', wholename='***', birthday=datetime.date(1986, 7, 5), gender='male', no='800052', level=7, salary=8000)

jiangy = Teacher('jiangy', wholename='***', birthday=datetime.date(1986, 10, 5), gender='female', no='800026', level=10, salary=3000)

chenjy = Teacher('chenjy', wholename='***', birthday=datetime.date(1986, 7, 5), gender='female', no='80005*', level=10, salary=3000)

AllDifferent([zjc, song, jiangy, chenjy])
# society.save()

close_world(society)
```

Following is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/william/Folders/ontology/owlsociety.py", line 88, in <module>
    close_world(society)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/owlready2/close.py", line 90, in close_world
    close_world(individual, Properties, close_instance_list, recursive)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/owlready2/close.py", line 45, in close_world
    elif len(range_classes) == 1:              self.is_a.append(Prop.only(range_classes[0]))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/owlready2/util.py", line 58, in append
    def append(self, x):          old = list(self); super().append(x)         ; self._callback(self._obj, old)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/owlready2/individual.py", line 177, in _instance_is_a_changed
    if isinstance(base, ClassConstruct): base._set_ontology(self.namespace.ontology)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/owlready2/class_construct.py", line 247, in _set_ontology
    if isinstance(self.value,    ClassConstruct): self.value   ._set_ontology(ontology)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/owlready2/class_construct.py", line 150, in _set_ontology
    super()._set_ontology(ontology)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/owlready2/class_construct.py", line 44, in _set_ontology
    raise OwlReadySharedBlankNodeError("A ClassConstruct cannot be shared by two ontologies, because it correspond to a RDF blank node. Please create a dupplicate.")
owlready2.base.OwlReadySharedBlankNodeError: A ClassConstruct cannot be shared by two ontologies, because it correspond to a RDF blank node. Please create a dupplicate.
```

Comment: (I love the title of this question.)

Comment: @Richard, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-world_assumption

Comment: What if declare `UniversityOrCollege` as an non-anonymous class and then use it?

Comment: @StanislavKralin That's one of the worst things in OWL modeling :D This reminds me of the classes in schema.org, there are lots of such classes which encode the logical union in the class name.

Comment: @StanislavKralin thank you, I understand now, partly at least.

Answer (score 2):

The error is thrown when Owlready tries to close anonymous `Unversity|College` class.

Declare the class explicitly:

```
class TertiaryEducationalInstitution(Institution):
    equivalent_to = [University|College]
```

And then use it:

```
class Teacher(Employee):
    equivalent_to = [Person & empolied.min(1, TertiaryEducationalInstitution)]

close_world(society)
```